Crazy mouse jumps
How do you fix the mouse wheel acting insane?
Whenever I tab back a browser window with a scrollable pane, and scroll using my mouse, the window scroll position often "jumps" wildly. Meaning, I might turn the mouse scroll wheel one click, but the window acts like I scrolled 100,000 clicks and jumps me pages up or pages down.
At first I thought it was just some buggy mouse, but I've tried multiple wireless mice, and it happens with all of them, so I have to assume it's some weird event issue in Gnome.
I've found if I first click on a dead area of the screen to ensure that window is explicitly in focus and then scroll, then scrolling works normally.
Anyone else notice this behavior? I'm running Ubuntu 22.04, although it happened in 20.04 too.
